# Create DropDown with predefined values in asp.net mvc 3 using Razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am making a partial view form my form. In it I want to display a drop down using 3 values, something like :

```
<td>
    @Html.DropDownList("Yes", "No", "Not Applicable")
</td>
```

Obviously I can not hard code the values like that, but this is the idea. I'll use this drop down only in this view so I want to keep the logic here if possible, the only thing is that I want to keep track on the selected value so I would like to add some hidden value like `Id` for example. Is there a way to do this in my view? I thought about passing a ViewBag argument or something like this but I really think that there must be a more elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ViewData["myList"] = 
                new SelectList(new[] { "10", "15", "25", "50", "100", "1000" }
                .Select(x => new {value = x, text = x}), 
                "value", "text", "15");
```

Then in your view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList")
```

or you can use linq to generate the select list

```
IList<Customer> customers = repository.GetAll<Customer>();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = 
    from c in customers
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Selected = (c.CustomerID == invoice.CustomerID),
        Text = c.Name,
        Value = c.CustomerID.ToString()
    };
```

In your case:

```
    List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();

    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = true });
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = false });
    ls.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Not Applicable", Value = "NULL", Selected = false });

    ViewData["myList"] = ls;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need this data only in `View`, you can write without helpers:

```
<select name="PropertyName" id="PropertyName">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Not Applicable">Not Applicable</option>
</select>
```

And select item with `jquery`

**OR**

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "PropertyName", 
    new SelectList(
        (new List {"Yes", "No", "Not Applicable"}).Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),
        "Value",
        "Text",
        "SelectedValue"
    )
)
```

**OR**

```
<select name="PropertyName" id="PropertyName">
    @{string[] list = new string[] { "Yes", "No", "Not Applicable" };}
    @foreach (var item in list)
    {
        <option @if(item == "SelectedValue") { <text>selected="selected"</text> } value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: I like the second option. Seems pretty clean.